# How do I remove the black box border from my magento website?

Tags: css, magento2.4, html

Please help me, I can not seem to figure out a way to remove the black border box surrounding all my product images and containers.

My website is [tucsons.ng](https://tucsons.ng)

Here is a sample of what I really want gone

my site right now = https://postimg.cc/xXCq5SBg

my desired result = https://postimg.cc/V0gL97R3

Comment: Try editing .css file

Comment: Please which of the css, there's like alot of css file in every folder where my theme-name appears, please point me to which even if it might not be particular but at least......

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.products-grid .product-item-info .product-item-photo  from this class in css remove border

Comment: found the product-1.css file under /html/app/design/frontend/Sm/smartech/web/css edited it out and i have been solved

Thanks